# Trying to understand stack layout

Tags: exploit, memory, c

I'm trying to do [this simple string format vulnerability exercise](http://pastebin.com/Dsx2aTPC) (it's not for homework, university semester ended 1 month ago in Australia).

There's a password checking function that holds the password and compares input against it byte-by-byte.

According to the function, there should be 4 variables on the stack, the guess string, the password string, the print response (empty before a guess) and number of tries left.

I've been reading Shellcoder's handbook and TAOSA, to my understanding the two arrays should be one after the other in this function's stack frame. So simply entering enough `%x%x` should print it out in hex, then I can convert to ASCII and that's the password.

So far an example of password being:

> WPK1ZHv1wubJ

gives out

> 590481d86720756f73736575203a64657825782578257825

from the stack.

However this does not change no matter what the password is (the password is taken from `/dev/random` each run).

What am I doing wrong here?

Note:

I have turned off ASLR with `sysctl kernel.randomize_va_space=0` and compiled it with `-fno-stack-protector -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2`